# Zuul filter return value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

What is the possible usage of `ZuulFilter.run()` return value?
All the examples (for instance [Spring example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/)) return `null`.
The official documentation [says](http://netflix.github.io/zuul/javadoc/zuul-core/com/netflix/zuul/IZuulFilter.html#run()):

> Some arbitrary artifact may be returned. Current implementation ignores it.

So why to have it at all?

Answer (score 1):

I've used this lib in multiple projects and I never thought to look into and stumbled upon this question so I had to look. Just tracing the code in IntelliJ, it does look like the results are pointless.

I'm on `zuul-core:1.3.1`:

Looking at `FilterProcessor`, when the routing methods are called to route based on the type, they all call `runFilters(sType)` which ultimately get the the return Object in question of the implementing `IZuulFilter` classes. The trail seems to stop here.

I then stopped to looked at their test classes and nothing seems to do anything with the return Object either nor the `ZuulFilterResult` that wraps it.

I then thought, ok, well maybe there is a way to pass data from one `IZuulFilter` to another (e.g. from pre to route) but that doesn't seem possible either since `FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(ZuulFilter)` doesn't do anything with the results and just passes it back to `runFilters(sType)` which we know ignores it.

My next line of questioning was, "well, perhaps you can provide your own `FilterProcessor` implementation and swap it out and actually use the Object somewhere". But alas, it looks like that isn't the case either unless you want/need to implement a lot more even into the `ZuulServlet`?

Lastly, I thought, "well, maybe it's just a convention thing". But `java.lang.Runnable.run()` is void and `javax.servlet.Filter.doFilter` is also void.

So for now, my best guess is that like all of us at some point in our careers, we sometimes fall into a [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) situation; perhaps this is just one example.